# My radiator doesn't empty completely, so after drain and refill, I know there is some radiator flush left in the system. is this bad?

Tags: radiator, flush

I have a motorhome with anFord F53 chassis and v-10 engine. The radiator system is listed as 30.9 quarts capacity.  when I drain I only get about 10 quarts. I added 44 oz of radiator flush and drain/refill/drain refill (with distilled water) three times.  This will leave about 20 oz of flush in the system (I think).

does it hurt anything to leave this amount of flush solution on a 30 quart sytem, or should I keep going on the drain/refill cycle

Comment: Did you drain the engine / block? Often bleed valves are for draining as well as bleeding.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

> I added 44 oz of radiator flush and drain/refill/drain refill (with
> distilled water) three times.

After flushing with distilled water 3X the flush is well diluted.  While it would be best to drain it all out, there is obviously no way to do that apart from disassembling the entire cooling system and draining each component.

I'd assume that the remaining flush is just distilled water and adjust your coolant mix appropriately to get the desired ratio.  Better yet, get a anti-freeze tester that shows the ratio and adjust until you get it right.